# create new array php multidimensional

Tags: php, arrays

I have array

```
Array
 (
    [0] => Array
      (
        [question_summary] => 
        [answer1] => 18
        [answer2] => 3
        [PercentEVQ] => 10.8000
        [PercentEVQ2] => 11
        [driver_display_name] => Position
        [cluster_name] => Personal Impact
      )

     [1] => Array
      (
        [question_summary] => 
        [answer1] => 51
        [answer2] => 3
        [PercentEVQ] => 30.6000
        [PercentEVQ2] => 31
        [driver_display_name] => Position
        [cluster_name] => Personal Impact
      )
)
```

how to create new array become

```
Array
(
     [Personal Impact] => Array
      (
          [Position] => array
           (
              [0] => array
               (
                   [question_summary] => 
                   [answer1] => 18
                   [answer2] => 3
                   [PercentEVQ] => 10.8000
                   [PercentEVQ2] => 11
                   [driver_display_name] => Position
                   [driver_name] => Position
                   [cluster_name] => Personal Impact
               )
               [1] => Array
                (
                   [question_summary] => 
                   [answer1] => 51
                   [answer2] => 3
                   [PercentEVQ] => 30.6000
                   [PercentEVQ2] => 31
                   [driver_display_name] => Position
                   [driver_name] => Position
                   [cluster_name] => Personal Impact
                )
         )      
     )
)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: [Sure](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+array+group+by).

Comment: give me enlighment ;)

Comment: I can help you too. You'll find the information you need [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). The second one is kind of long, but I highly advise you to read the whole thing, it will help you out a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible you can just `foreach(your values as key => value) {}` it or something like this:

[Sample Fiddle](http://ideone.com/ZBy4QV)

```
<?php
$new_values = array();
foreach($old_values as $key => $values) {
    $new_values[$values['cluster_name']][$values['driver_display_name']][] = array(
        'answer1' => $values['answer1'],
        'answer2' => $values['answer2'],
        'PercentEVQ' => $values['PercentEVQ'],
        'PercentEVQ2' => $values['PercentEVQ2'],
        'driver_display_name' => $values['driver_display_name'],
        'cluster_name' => $values['cluster_name'],
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you defining a new array?

`$new_array['Personal Impact']['Position'] = $old_array;`

Comment: For *this example* your code is correct. But I believe the OP wants to group the sub-arrays by `cluster_name`, then by `driver_display_name`.

Comment: yup...how to group it... :D